# How to sort an NSArray of Objects to alphabetic NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I have a custom class called `Receipt`. It has property of another class called `Retailer`. `Retailer` has another property called `retailerName`.

I get an array of `Receipt` objects. I want it to be sorted to an `NSDictionary` whose keys will be alphabets and value will be a array of `Receipt` whose `Retailer` object's `retailerName` begins with the alphabet and the array is sorted alphabetically.

**What I have :**

```
[
  {
    "retailerName": "Adidas",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "Book My Show",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "Albert-Heijn",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "Amazon",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "BlackBerry",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "Lambhorgini",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "Lewis Outlet",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "Boston Store",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  },
  {
    "retailerName": "Lidl",
    "totalCost": 392.1,
    "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
  }
]
```

**What I need from it :**

```
{
    "A": [
          {
              "retailerName": "Adidas",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          },
          {
              "retailerName": "Albert-Heijn",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          },
          {
              "retailerName": "Amazon",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          }
          ],
    "B": [
          {
              "retailerName": "BlackBerry",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          },
          {
              "retailerName": "Book My Show",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          },
          {
              "retailerName": "Boston Store",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          }
          ],
    "L": [
          {
              "retailerName": "Lambhorgini",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          },
          {
              "retailerName": "Lewis Outlet",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          },
          {
              "retailerName": "Lidl",
              "totalCost": 392.1,
              "purchasedOn": 1461218024549
          }
          ]
}
```

I know the scenario is little complicated, but I have tried my best to be explanative. Ask for further explanation if required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried anything? do you have any code , please share

Comment: Nope. I have nothing to share

Comment: First try by yourself if you face any issue then post here .

Comment: I just solved my problem, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem :

Here is what I did :

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary (DictionaryForSectionIndex)

+(NSMutableDictionary *)createDictionaryForSectionIndex:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (char firstChar = 'a'; firstChar <= 'z'; firstChar++)
    {
        //NSPredicates are fast
        NSString *firstCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", firstChar];
        NSArray *content = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"retailerName beginswith[cd] %@", firstCharacter]];
        NSMutableArray *mutableContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:content];

        if ([mutableContent count] > 0)
        {
            NSString *key = [firstCharacter uppercaseString];
            [dict setObject:mutableContent forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return dict;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array = [Array
     sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
                          {
                              NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber
                              numberWithFloat:[someValue floatValue]];
                             NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber
                              numberWithFloat:[[somevalue floatValue]];

                              return [number2 compare:number1];
                        }];
```

You can chose on specific key in a dictionary and try sorting it